# python numpy find y value based on x value

Tags: python, numpy

I want to get column y that has maximum x value.
If I have

```
arr = [[1, 1],[1, 2],[3, 0],[4, 7],[3, 1],[4, 6]]
```

Since the minimum x value is 1, I want the value 1 and 2.
So far, I got the minimum x value by

```
min = np.amin(arr, axis=0)
```

but I don't know how to get the other value which has the min value

Answer (score 1):

Use [`np.min`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.min.html) to find the minimum *x-coordinate* and then [boolean indexing](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html#boolean-array-indexing) to find all the matching values.

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([[1, 1], [1, 2], [3, 0], [4, 7], [3, 1], [4, 6]])

# find the minimum across the x coordinate
mi = np.min(arr[:, 0])

# find all the positions equals to the minimum using boolean indexing and get the y coordinate
res = arr[arr[:, 0] == mi, 1]

print(res)
```

**Output**

```
[1 2]
```

Note: Don't use `min` as a variable name because it shadows the built-in function.

Comment: I was thinking at `arr[arr[:,0]==arr[:,0].min(), 1]` to do it in one line, but it is the same of your answer.